# Adding own Actor to a table

Tags: libgdx

I try to add my own actor to a table which is in a group:

Following is working without using a group:

- Creating a table
- add myActor to the table
- position table to 300,300
- adding table to stage

I can see the table and I can see my own actor on the screen. 
checking getX() of my actor when drawing -> 250 (my table has a with of 100)
Great !

now the problem:

- Creating Group
- Creating a table
- add myActor to the table
- adding table to Group
- adding Group to stage
- position group to 300,300

I can't see my actor
check getX() of my actor when drawing -> -23

What is wrong here ? What is the difference. How does positions be propagated to chlid actors ?

Comment: Please provide the code that is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your actor does not report its minimum, maximum and preferred size and thus the table cannot lay out properly.